# NativeScript: @nativescript/geolocation vs nativescript-google-maps-sdk

Tags: nativescript, nativescript-vue, nativescript-plugin

> Error executing Static Binding Generator: File already exists. This may lead to undesired behavior.
> Please change the name of one of the extended classes.
> File:C:\repo\geo\geoapp\platforms\android\app\src\main\java\com\tns\FragmentClass.java Class: com.tns.FragmentClass

I keep getting this error.  It started with trying to get the `@nativescript/geolocation` plug-in to work. It compiled, however the app will crash when the `geolocation.watchLocation()` method was called.  This is what I was trying to fix.  I ran the `ns clean` a few times, rebooted, and delete the `c:\users\<username>\.gradle` folder.  Deleting the .gradle folder worked when I had this error before.

It could be something to do with also using the `nativescript-google-maps-sdk` plug-in.  I believe there is a know issue with the the `googlePlayServicesVersion`.  I tried those options as well without any joy.  I am a bit confused to which file I should edit; some mention `/app/App_Resources/Android/app.gradle`, others `app/App_Resources/Android/before-plugins.gradle`,  I tried both.

Any advise will be much appreciated.

```
"dependencies": {
    "@nativescript/core": "~8.1.1",
    "@nativescript/theme": "~3.0.1",
    "nativescript-vue": "~2.9.0",
    "vuex": "~3.6.2",
    "@nativescript/geolocation": "7.0.0",
    "@nativescript/directions": "~2.0.1",
    "@nativescript/social-share": "~2.0.4",
    "@triniwiz/nativescript-couchbase": "~1.2.5",
    "@triniwiz/nativescript-toasty": "~4.1.3",
    "@bradmartin/nativescript-urlhandler": "~2.0.1",
    "nativescript-google-maps-sdk" : "3.0.2",
    "nativescript-gif": "~5.0.0"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@nativescript/android": "8.1.1",
    "@nativescript/webpack": "~5.0.0",
    "nativescript-vue-template-compiler": "~2.9.0",
    "@vue/devtools": "^5.3.4",
    "@triniwiz/nativescript-toasty": "~4.1.3",
    "@triniwiz/nativescript-socketio": "4.0.1",
    "nativescript-vue-devtools": "1.5.1"
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

Fixed! In a attempt to narrow down the underlying issue, I created a new project, copied the original code over bit by bit running a `ns build android` command in between. Turns out to be a few old package references (`import Something from 'some-packages'`) from when I was switching the old *tns-* packages to the new *@nativescript* packages. The one package however required a further use of the --force options (`ns build android --force`) before it started to work.

In term of **@nativescript/geolocation vs nativescript-google-maps-sdk** part, that was fixed by adding a *App_Resources\Android\before-plugins.gradle* file with the following contents

```
android {
    project.ext { 
        googlePlayServicesVersion = "16.+"
    }
    dependencies {
        def googlePlayServicesVersion = project.googlePlayServicesVersion
        compile "com.google.android.gms:play-services-location:$googlePlayServicesVersion"
    }
}
```